# Optional and required properties in TS interfaces

Tags: typescript, interface

here I have simple example typescript interfaces:

```
interface A: {
   id: number;
   email: string;
}

interface B extends A {
   login: string;
   password: string;
}
```

What I want: IF I create an object from interface A all properties are required. If I create B - the 'email' property from A is optional, all other properties (B) are required. Is it possible ?

Comment: I don't exactly understand. As currently written, the properties from `A` will be required in `B`, since they were required in `A`. You can make them optional if you do `interface B extends Partial<A>`, or if the properties in `A` were optional you could  write `interface B extends Required<A>` to make them required

Comment: Is it you just want email Optional?

Comment: Split `A` into differen interfaces. Or use something like `type A_OptionalEmail = Omit<A, "email"> & {email?: string}` ans extend B from that.

Comment: `type AforB = Partial<Pick<A, 'email'>> & Omit<A, 'email'>`  and then -> `interface B extends AforB  {`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution. You need to `pick` the email property from A:

```js
Pick<A,"email">
```

and make it optional with the PArtial

```js
interface B extends Partial<Pick<A,"email">>
```

Full code and  [playgorung](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN4FgBQz-AAmAXMiAK4C2ARtANy77ISVzAA2pAzmFKAOYMcAX1y5QkWIhQAhZgA9IIQl2QAFOFDDA47ADxrgCANZ7UAGgBELNu0sA%20e5kb52Ae36huvAUKYAHOC4uAHc3KBJkHj4QQVxRHFwENxAeZDhSdABeZzxmVg5iS0tzFyJSAFZSkTEcZNSwZGpSORzsPPdPEFJLSB4Sl0DgsIievrABmsScAHoZ5GBG3S43dIQkfzBVSAALfNtkfyg3fySUtIQW5DaXTq9kXoh%206vwh0PDIx%20eXG0KH8cs8VqcwWjRCHHYyGSlH87DYIHS1Dc5EaYB2KCIh2Opzq50akVauVcHnuXwmL0OQXeo3%20T3JZUiADZqsIgA)

```js
interface A {
   id: number;
   email: string;
}

interface B extends Partial<Pick<A,"email">> {
   login: string;
   password: string;
}
```